# Regular expression that match each character uppercase but not the first character

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expressions that match each character uppercase but not the first character.

For example:
With string `ClassTrainingFramework` will match `T` and `F`.
I will use this regular expressions to transform to `class_training_framework`.
So, What is the right regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

You may try as below and capture all groups :

```
[A-Z]?[a-z]*([A-Z])[a-z]*
```

Test Cases:

> Test Case 1: ClassTrainingFramework Group 1 : T Group 2 : F
>
> Test Case 2: classTrainingFramework Group 1 : T Group 2 : F

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ex07Rb/1)

Hope it helps.